# Temporary root shell on unlocked bootloader?

Tags: root-access

My Pixel 2 "walleye" is already bootloader unlocked. I am wondering whether it's possible to get a root shell without first rooting the phone. Maybe via fastboot?

Comment: yes, if your device accept `fastboot boot`

Comment: https://twrp.me/google/googlepixel2.html

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk

Comment: get a backup of boot.emmc.win, patch with magisk apk, and fastboot boot magisk_patched.img

Comment: How do I acquire boot.emmc.win?

Comment: `fastboot boot twrp-3.3.0-0-walleye.img` in TWRP menu - backup - boot

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EDK1.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6DS4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMKKi.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8aWV.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Qyg.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs06m.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ03m.jpg